# Dynamic Spacing Between Col in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a row of 3 different columns which change sizes depending on the screen size. However, when I shrink the screen, I want the margin to change only for a certain number of boxes. For example, this is what it looks like when there is no margin on the left or right.

**XL Screen**

[image: No margin]

This is what it looks like when I scale down the screen size with no margin.

**L Screen**
[image: Scaled down no margin]

However, when I change the margin to "mr-4", the boxes do not scale down the same way. Here is how it looks with margin on the first and second boxes.

**XL Screen**
[image: Scaled down no margin]
**L Screen**
[image]

This is the html I'm working with

```css
.cram-set-header{
  color: #042157;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.cram-set{
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #CBCBCB;
  padding-left: 28px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>

<body>
<div id="subject-container" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row pt-1">
          <h3 id="subject-text">My Sets</h3>
          <span class="num-cram-sets pt-1 ml-2">- 8 Cram Sets</span>

        </div>
        <div class="row ml-auto">
          <div class="col-8 pr-0 pb-3">
            <button class="btn" id="sign-up-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3 mr-4">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-2">

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I want to be able to mantain the margin between boxes when the screen size is minimized. I thought about creating a class and then using media queries to change the margin depending on screen size, but I need every box to have margin at some point.

For example, in the XL screen size, I do not want right margin on the box on the right because I want it to be flush with the end of the column.

https://repl.it/join/tgbodxoh-claytonhorning

Comment: Is there other CSS? Note that Bootstrap `row` should not be the immediate child of another `row`. Only columns should be the immediate child of `row`.

Comment: Yes, there is other CSS but nothing that would affect the margin. Here is a replit https://repl.it/join/tgbodxoh-claytonhorning. The row actually doesn't serve any purpose except to align the row with the edge of the column. I wasn't sure how else to do it.

Comment: Repl.it not visible

Comment: Are you logged in? Not sure what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

To solve that I suggest you use **flex-wrap: wrap**. I add some classes to your HTML and fixed the problem. I hope you like it.
For the XL screen, I made **row-container** flex-wrap: nowrap because otherwise, it will send the box to the next line earlier.

```
.row-container {
  display:flex;
  flex:0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.cram-set-header{
  color: #042157;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
}

.cram-set{
  flex-basis:25%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 120px;
  padding-top: 32px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #CBCBCB;
  padding-left: 28px;
  margin:10px;
}
.row-header {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex:0 0 100%;
  
}
.row-header .row.pt-1 {
  flex-basis:50%;
  margin:10px;
}
.row-header .row.ml-auto {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  flex-basis:50%;
  margin:30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px){
  .row-container {
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
  
}
```

```
<body>
<div id="subject-container" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">

    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row row-header">
        <div class="row pt-1">
          <h3 id="subject-text">My Sets</h3>
          <span class="num-cram-sets pt-1 ml-2">- 8 Cram Sets</span>

        </div>
        <div class="row ml-auto">
          <div class="col-8 pr-0 pb-3">
            <button class="btn" id="sign-up-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadModal">Upload</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row row-container">
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3 mr-4">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set mb-3">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4 cram-set">
          <h5 class="cram-set-header mb-0">Marketing - Cram Set #1</h5>
          <div class="row pl-3">
            <p class="mr-1">5.0</p>
            <img src="img/star-rating.png" alt="" height="16px">
            <p class="ml-2">1,034 Questions</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-2">

  </div>
</div>
</body>
```